# How to make entire div clickable?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make [4 boxes](http://www.designwhizz.com/) to be clickable in entire area but without success.

This is the boxes:
[image: four green boxes in a row]

Currently only the text inside boxes are clickable, but I'm trying to make the entire box clickable. I searched for CSS for entire box separated, and found this:

```
.slist_sc_2 .slist_item { 
    transition: all 0ms; 
    padding: 30px 25px 20px 25px; 
    height: 270px; 
    overflow: hidden;  
    float: left; 
    display: block; 
    width: calc(25% - 30px); 
    margin:0 40px 40px 0
}
```

I did research and found this [codepen](http://codepen.io/mrotaru/pen/Gydrp) that functions the same way as I am trying to do on my site, but I don't know how to integrate it. Can someone  give me some advice on what to change to make it work in that way?

Updated HTML from that part:

```
<h2 style="font-weight:normal;">Other Services</h2></div></div><style type="text/css">.slist_sc_2 .slist_item {border: 5px #eeeeee solid; background-color: #44dd61}.slist_sc_2 .slist_item:hover {border-color:#26b7e7; background-color: #26b7e7}.slist_sc_2 .slist_item .ss2_header h3 a {color: #ffffff}.slist_sc_2 .slist_item:hover .ss2_header h3 a {color: #ffffff}.slist_sc_2 .slist_item .ss2_description, .slist_sc_2 .slist_item .ss2_description a {color: #ffffff}.slist_sc_2 .slist_item:hover .ss2_description, .slist_sc_2 .slist_item:hover .ss2_description a {color: #ffffff}</style><div class="slist_sc_2  text-center"><div class="slist_item">
                                    <div class="ss2_icon"><img src="http://www.designwhizz.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Paint-Brush-100.png"  alt="Complex designs"></div>
                                    <div class="ss2_header"><h3><a href="http://www.designwhizz.com/service/complex-designs/">Complex designs</a></h3></div>
                                    <div class="ss2_description"><a href="http://www.designwhizz.com/service/complex-designs/"></a></div>
                                </div><div class="slist_item">
                                    <div class="ss2_icon"><img src="http://www.designwhizz.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Google-Sites-100.png"  alt="Search engine optimisation"></div>
                                    <div class="ss2_header"><h3><a href="http://www.designwhizz.com/service/search-engine-optimisation/">Search engine optimisation</a></h3></div>
                                    <div class="ss2_description"><a href="http://www.designwhizz.com/service/search-engine-optimisation/"></a></div>
                                </div><div class="slist_item">
                                    <div class="ss2_icon"><img src="http://www.designwhizz.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Facebook-100.png"  alt="Social media management"></div>
                                    <div class="ss2_header"><h3><a href="http://www.designwhizz.com/service/social-media-management/">Social media management</a></h3></div>
                                    <div class="ss2_description"><a href="http://www.designwhizz.com/service/social-media-management/"></a></div>
                                </div><div class="slist_item">
                                    <div class="ss2_icon"><img src="http://www.designwhizz.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Blog-100.png"  alt="Content generation"></div>
                                    <div class="ss2_header"><h3><a href="http://www.designwhizz.com/service/content-generation/">Content generation</a></h3></div>
                                    <div class="ss2_description"><a href="http://www.designwhizz.com/service/content-generation/"></a></div>
                                </div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the link absolute and relative to the main container. See sample below.

```css
.slist_sc_2 .slist_item { 
    transition: all 0ms; 
    padding: 30px 25px 20px 25px; 
    /**height: 270px; removed for testing purposes**/
    overflow: hidden;  
    float: left; 
    display: block; 
    width: calc(25% - 30px); 
    margin:0 40px 40px 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center; /**Added for testing purposes**/
}
.ss2_header h3 > a {
  position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h2 style="font-weight:normal;">Other Services</h2></div></div><style type="text/css">.slist_sc_2 .slist_item {border: 5px #eeeeee solid; background-color: #44dd61}.slist_sc_2 .slist_item:hover {border-color:#26b7e7; background-color: #26b7e7}.slist_sc_2 .slist_item .ss2_header h3 a {color: #ffffff}.slist_sc_2 .slist_item:hover .ss2_header h3 a {color: #ffffff}.slist_sc_2 .slist_item .ss2_description, .slist_sc_2 .slist_item .ss2_description a {color: #ffffff}.slist_sc_2 .slist_item:hover .ss2_description, .slist_sc_2 .slist_item:hover .ss2_description a {color: #ffffff}</style><div class="slist_sc_2  text-center"><div class="slist_item">
                                    <div class="ss2_icon"><img src="http://www.designwhizz.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Paint-Brush-100.png"  alt="Complex designs"></div>
                                    <div class="ss2_header"><h3><a href="http://www.designwhizz.com/service/complex-designs/">Complex designs</a></h3></div>
                                    <div class="ss2_description"><a href="http://www.designwhizz.com/service/complex-designs/"></a></div>
                                </div><div class="slist_item">
                                    <div class="ss2_icon"><img src="http://www.designwhizz.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Google-Sites-100.png"  alt="Search engine optimisation"></div>
                                    <div class="ss2_header"><h3><a href="http://www.designwhizz.com/service/search-engine-optimisation/">Search engine optimisation</a></h3></div>
                                    <div class="ss2_description"><a href="http://www.designwhizz.com/service/search-engine-optimisation/"></a></div>
                                </div><div class="slist_item">
                                    <div class="ss2_icon"><img src="http://www.designwhizz.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Facebook-100.png"  alt="Social media management"></div>
                                    <div class="ss2_header"><h3><a href="http://www.designwhizz.com/service/social-media-management/">Social media management</a></h3></div>
                                    <div class="ss2_description"><a href="http://www.designwhizz.com/service/social-media-management/"></a></div>
                                </div><div class="slist_item">
                                    <div class="ss2_icon"><img src="http://www.designwhizz.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Blog-100.png"  alt="Content generation"></div>
                                    <div class="ss2_header"><h3><a href="http://www.designwhizz.com/service/content-generation/">Content generation</a></h3></div>
                                    <div class="ss2_description"><a href="http://www.designwhizz.com/service/content-generation/"></a></div>
                                </div><div style="clear: left"></div></div><div style="clear: left"></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: This works ok, but makes squares a little bit smassed. See image:

http://i.imgur.com/SBgF8nD.png?1

The same is shown in your preview too. :)

Comment: This should work. The code you posted that was what i used  maybe its missing some properties. I tried it on the link above and it worked. I just messed with the a tag not the width or height

Comment: after inserting your code, blocks looks smashed like is shown on image. how to fix that? Also in your code execution preview blocks looks smasshed.

Comment: give the main container div holding that whole section a width of 100%;

Comment: That makes sense. Added :

`.slist_sc_2 .slist_item { 
    transition: all 0ms; 
    padding: 30px 25px 20px 25px; 
    /**height: 270px; removed for testing purposes**/
    overflow: hidden;  
    float: left; 
    display: block; 
    width: 260px; 
    margin:0 40px 40px 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center; /**Added for testing purposes**/
}`

and finally works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can just wrap the entire element in an anchor tag:

```css
.slist_sc_2 .slist_item {
background:#000;
transition: all 0ms; 
padding: 30px 25px 20px 25px; 
height: 270px; 
overflow: hidden;  
float: left; 
display: block; 
width: calc(25% - 30px); 
margin:0 40px 40px 0
}
```

```html
<div class="slist_sc_2">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="slist_item">Box 1</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="slist_item">Box 2</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="slist_item">Box 3</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="slist_item">Box 4</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to give the anchor `display: block;` then, otherwise this is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Simply define `:active`.  If you want to add JavaScript functionality add jQuery with a `.click` function.  Just comment if you need the latter.

```css
.slist_sc_2 .slist_item 
{ 
transition: all 0ms; 
padding: 30px 25px 20px 25px; 
height: 270px; 
overflow: hidden;  
float: left; 
display: block; 
width: calc(25% - 30px); 
margin:0 40px 40px 0;

  cursor:pointer;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none; 
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

.slist_sc_2 .slist_item:active
{ 
color:red;
background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="slist_sc_2">
  <div class="slist_item">
    Test
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Makes the boxes as link, but not point nowhere.. See image from html : http://i.imgur.com/2QsLiAQ.png?1

Answer (score 1):

If you won't set it up in js, nothing will happen when you click on the div,
But if you just want it to appear clickable, oyu can try adding this to your CSS:

```
.slist_sc_2 .slist_item:hover
{ 
cursor: pointer;
}
```

That will change the cursor to a hand cursor on hover which will make it look clickable.

Comment: Thanks, but looks like only makes entire form as link. How to link each box separated ?

Comment: @Dora that depends on your html. I assumed the boxes are of class slist_item OR slist_sc_2.  if only one of them applies, or a different class altogether, you'll need to change the selector to reflect that. (going over the site you linked to, use only .slist_item)

Comment: @Dora It's a bit hard to debug without seeing the html you're working with. Could you update your question with it?

Comment: Added HTML from that part. Can you take a look ?

Comment: @Dora I made a fiddle from what you've sent and it seems to work fine- https://jsfiddle.net/jh09wxsw/1/

Also note- your html has some embeded styling (css) so you might want to move that to your CSS file for better management.

Comment: I checked you fiddle, but looks linked are only text, entire form is not yet. I need entire box to link to the same URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with javascript/jquery, you can add an attribute to the div to specify the URL, then change the `window.location` to that URL on click.

```js
$('div').on('click',function() {
  window.location.href = $(this).attr('data-href');
})
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-href="//google.com"></div>
<div data-href="//stackoverflow.com"></div>
```

Comment: Codes are inserted via Visual Composer, so this code not works for me.

Comment: @Dora then you should put that and any other limitations in your post so we don't waste one another's time. Also I don't understand why this doesn't work. I don't know what Visual Composer is. What are your limitations?

Comment: also links are not defined as data-href. Do you see first post?

Comment: @Dora you haven't said what your limitations are. You can't modify the HTML or add javascript?